# What are the performance implications to adding *all* styled-system attributes to a styled-component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

When using `styled-system` with `styled-components` what, if any, are performance implications to loading in more props than I may use?

For example, this is what I currently have for a base `Div` component, but there are tons of other props I'm *not* using -- e.g., `fontSize` and `fontSizeProps` as two of dozens of other examples.

```
import React from 'react';
import { themed } from 'Utils/theme.helpers';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {
 alignSelf,
 AlignSelfProps,
 height,
 HeightProps,
 maxHeight,
 MaxHeightProps,
 maxWidth,
 MaxWidthProps,
 minHeight,
 MinHeightProps,
 minWidth,
 MinWidthProps,
 order,
 OrderProps,
 overflow,
 OverflowProps,
 space,
 SpaceProps,
 width,
 WidthProps,
} from 'styled-system';

export type DivProps = React.PureComponent<JSX.IntrinsicElements['div']> &
 AlignSelfProps &
 OrderProps &
 OverflowProps &
 SpaceProps &
 WidthProps &
 MaxWidthProps &
 MinWidthProps &
 MaxHeightProps &
 HeightProps &
 MinHeightProps;

export const Div = styled.div<DivProps>(
    {
 boxSizing: 'border-box',
    },
 space,
 width,
 minWidth,
 maxWidth,
 height,
 minHeight,
 maxHeight,
 order,
 alignSelf,
 overflow,
 themed('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's negligible.

[image]

1. The top 3 Empty divs are styled-system components with no props.
2. The colored divs are derived from your Div example with 1 color prop each.
3. The last styled div is just a styled-component without styled-system.

I suppose you could scale this out with much more complex components but I think the render times will grow in linear time.

Comment: Can i interpret this as styled-components without styled-system are 3 times faster?

Comment: I wouldn't interpet it like that.  Styled-system is a great system.  It's used in a lot of great styling systems like [Rebass](https://rebassjs.org/).  It's as fast as any other styling system.  It's a framework like any other styling framework.  If you enjoy designing with frameworks then use one.  Performance is not a concern.